# DATE/TIME in oracle - date duration function

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I am trying to create a function that can subtract between 2 dates but I am having some issues:

Firstly with the storing of the date, and secondly with the function.

Here is my code for storing the date in to a table:

```
CREATE TABLE car_info
  (
   car_id NUMBER(4)
   arrival DATE,
   departure DATE
   ......
  )
```

here I have saved the arrival/departure times as DATES. Ideally I will want it in the format of dd-mon-yyy-hh-mm-ss

This is where I encounter my first problem:

```
INSERT INTO car_info 
VALUES('0001', to_date('12-jun-2006 06:00:01'), to_date('14-jun-2006 09:00:01')
```

From the research I have done, this seems correct?

however if I do a `SELECT * FROM car_info`, this is the result:

```
car_id       arrival_date      departure_date
   1          12-jun-2006        14-jun-2006
```

Does anyone know why it is not displaying the result as a full date and time?

To stop this post getting too full of information, once I have this problem solved I will post my issues with the function.

Thanks for any help

kihd regards, Darren

*Second part of question has been moved to [Oracle sql - date subtraction within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9533617)*

Comment: please ask about the function as a separate question; Vincent has answered the original question about the insert. It is considered bad form to ask more than one thing, and once answered far fewer people will look at it again.

Comment: To save time if you do ask a new question; `show errors function get_duration` will give you information on what is wrong, which you might want to include; and you should show what you want the caller to see returned - if you really want to return a formatted string, and exactly how it should look e.g. 'x day, y hours, z minutes'. Some sample data and expected output would be nice.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I will repost this next part about the function then as I am still struggling a bit. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DATE in Oracle is a point in time, it is not stored with a format. A format is chosen when the date is displayed so that it can be understood by humans.

DATE by default will be displayed as per your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. You can change this setting with the following command:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
```

You could also ask for an explicit format by using TO_CHAR in your query:

```
SELECT to_char(arrival, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  FROM car_info
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, (arrival, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), this has worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

A DATE column is held in the database encoded in 7 bytes, not as a formatted string. When you select a DATE column from the database the client tool you are using has to format it to display it in a meaningful way.  It does this using a default format mask.  How you set this depends on the tool you are using.  In SQL Plus, you can do this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Or you can format the date yoursefl in the query using TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle stores dates in a binary internal representation so how you enter them and the format you retrieve them can be set either at the session, database or query level.

You should generally explicitly format your dates when inserting to prevent any implicit conversion errors:

```
INSERT INTO car_info  
VALUES('0001', 
       to_date('12-jun-2006 06:00:01'), 
       to_date('14-jun-2006 09:00:01'))
```

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO car_info  
VALUES('0001', 
       to_date('12-jun-2006 06:00:01', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
       to_date('14-jun-2006 09:00:01', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

EDIT: The format models for Oracle dates etc. are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm).